# use of svn info command in ant script

Tags: svn, ant

actually i want to know the info of any folder or file through ant script using svn info tag.
so pls help me out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'$<!-- SVN info -->'
'<target name="svn-info">'
    <svn>
        <info
            path="/workspace/project/trunk"
            committedRevisionProperty="revisionVersion"
            authorProperty="revisionAuthor"
            committedDateProperty="revisionDate"
        />
    </svn>
    <!-- show revision, author and date -->
    <property
        name="version"
        value="At revision ${revisionVersion} by ${revisionAuthor} on ${revisionDate}"
    />
    <echo message="${version}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: but here it show that nested info tag is not allowed in svn tag